# Firebase migration 0.9 to 1.0

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

i had my firebase application deploy and running but after some changes it stopped working.
Following error while deployment.

```
Error: functions.config() is not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.
```

After updating both firebase-functions and firebase-admin

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save
```

All good until here...

Since functions.config() is deprecated and im currently using these two const to obtain bucket name and bucket.

```
const bucketName = functions.config().firebase.storageBucket
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
```

Im getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'storageBucket' of undefined

What should i change to fix it?, or what im doing wrong!??